# about some equivalence propositions to Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

At Section 16 of naive set theory by Holmos, the exercise asks me to prove that the following statements are equivalent to AC.

(1)every partially ordered set has a maximal chain.

(2)Every chain in a partially ordered set is included in some maximal chain.

However, I believe that both statements, when given the same condition of Zorn's lemma(every chain has an upper bound), are correct. But I don't know why without such condition, the two statements would be equivalent to AC.

Comment: Zorn's lemma is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.  So you cannot invoke Zorn's lemma without AC.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: What I mean is a partially ordered set, such that every chain has an upper bound, then it has a maximal chain for (1), the same for (2).

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Actually I am not invoking Zorn's lemma to prove the equivalence, I am just using the condition stated in Zorn's lemma and try to derive another conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that either one of these imply Zorn's lemma, when applied to a partial ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound.

To see that, note that if $(P,\leq)$ is such that every chain has an upper bound, then a maximal chain must include all its upper bound. In other words, it must include a maximum, which is a maximal element in $P$.

However, the condition itself does not concern itself with the existence of upper, and it shouldn't. In $(\Bbb N,\leq)$ there is a maximal chain, but it has no upper bound, and there is no maximal element either.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to verify, thank you Asaf. Of course I was about to use AC to prove these two, and the proof goes almost the same with (AC -> Zorn's lemma)